# Customising alerts in react-native

Tags: react-native, alert

Is there any way of customising native **Alert** component so it'll accept some components(like inputs and so on..) ? Please DO NOT suggest using some modals from npm and constructing something by hand, I know about these approaches...
I'm interested, if it's possible to render children components inside of native alert, because it accepts only title, message and actions and nothing else...

Comment: customize your own alert message using modal, check this out https://mmelikes.medium.com/custom-alert-in-react-native-using-context-api-28c2d81278d1

Answer (score 0):

more than text input no  and it only work for ios,from docs for ios yes(text input) alert ios,but you can't really customize it
even in native ios you can't customize it more than how is it

> This is an API that works both on Android and iOS and can show static alerts. To show an alert that prompts the user to enter some information, see AlertIOS; entering text in an alert is common on iOS only.
>
> link to it https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert